# Slide show in android

Tags: android, slideshow

I want to write slide show for my app like this picture.
how i can write some thing like that :

[image: view picture - what i want to do]

Comment: You may follow this tutorial [here](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewPager for this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

{
 private static final Integer[] IMAGES= {R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four};
    private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 init();

}


    private void init() {


        for(int i=0;i<IMAGES.length;i++)
            ImagesArray.add(IMAGES[i]);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this,ImagesArray));


        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
                findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        indicator.setRadius(5 * density);



        NUM_PAGES =IMAGES.length;



        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 30000, 30000);

        // Pager listener over indicator
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="10dip"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="#ff0099"
                app:pageColor="#FF0000"
                app:snap="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You are done :)